# Передать данные из google script в javascript

Tags: google-apps-script

Добрый день. Скрипт .gs вытаскивает данные из googlespreadsheets, подскажите, могу ли я как - то передать эти данные в javascript который находится в .html файле?

Comment: Не думаю. Тот код  должен выполняться на клиенте. Но если этот javascript выполняет запрос к API, например, то вы можете создать такой же запрос в вашем .gs скрипте

Comment: Можете попробовать встроить в Google Apps Script html страницу с javascript (даже jquery c некоторыми ограничениями), ели это то, что Вам надо.

Comment: Да. страница встроена, но как полученные из гугл таблиц  .gs скриптом данные передать во встроенный html с javascript. Хотелось бы просто создать связный выпадающий список из полученных данных.

Comment: Не путайте технологии. Ограничений на исполнение JQuery давно нет. Компилируется все и вся, работает надежно. Если речь идет именно об HtmlService, то надо вот так https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/fd0ffc5436bf49b1d831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, ваш вопрос не отражает ключевых особеннстей, поэтому понять, как решить эту задачу не представляется возможным.

Положим, что у вас критический вариант - страница хостится на вашем сервере.

Существует два способа получения данных:

- [Executing Functions using the Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute) Требует авторизации пользователя. Анонимус не пройдет. Возможна как серверная реализация, так и на клиенте.
- [Serving JSONP in web pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) JSONP, Карл!

Пример использования второго варианта.

Создаете и публикуете сервис в своем скрипте

```
function doGet(request) {
  var events = CalendarApp.getEvents(
    new Date(Number(request.parameters.start) * 1000),
    new Date(Number(request.parameters.end) * 1000));
  var result = {
    available: events.length == 0
  };
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    request.parameters.prefix + '(' + JSON.stringify(result) + ')')
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

Вызываете контент

```
<script src="URL_OF_YOUR_SCRIPT?start=1325437200&end=1325439000&prefix=alert">
</script>
```

Исполняете контент

```
alert({"available":true})
```